# How to ask IdP for user attributes in SAML

Tags: saml, opensaml

I have done a small piece of code which sends login and logout request and processes the corresponding responses using OpenSAML. If I'm not wrong I am supposed to be able to retrieve user attributes through SAML but I don't know how to ask for these attributes. I don't know if it is an added piece of XML in my requests or some kind of tweak in my IdP. Perhaps I'm wrong and asking for attributes is a separate SAML request.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Attributes *can* be included in the IdP's initial SAMLResponse OR there can be a separate AttributeQuery service call if the IdP supports it.

Comment: Thanks. How can I make them to be included in that initial response?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is separate request. You need to create AttributeQuery.

See [AttributeQuery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAML_2.0#SAML_Attribute_Query)